# docker: poorly formatted environment: variable contains whitespaces

Tags: docker, environment-variables, multiline

I have multi-line environment variables:

```
SINGLE_LINE=VALUE
MULTI_LINE=VA
LU E
```

I want to pass this environment variables using a file through `--env-file` parameter of `docker run`.
When I pass this file to a Docker container, using `--env-file`, it fails with a message:

```sh
export SINGLE_LINE=VALUE
export MULTI_LINE="VA
LU E"
env > .env
docker run -ti --rm --env-file .env busybox sh
```

```
docker: poorly formatted environment: variable 'LU E' contains whitespaces.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occur because the way docker parses this file it does not accept multi-line string and whitespaces in the key names. See relevant [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12997).

**Workaround**. Strip all line-endings from multi-line variables:

```sh
>.env
for var in $(compgen -v | grep -Ev '^(BASH)'); do
    var_fixed=$(printf "%s" "${!var}" | tr -d '\n' )
    echo "$var=${var_fixed}" >>.env
done
```

Each line explained:

1. `>.env` - make `.env` to be an empty file
2. `for var in $(compgen -v | grep -Ev '^(BASH)'); do` - iterate over env **keys**
3. `var_fixed=$(printf "%s" "${!var}" | tr -d '\n' )` - remove new-lines from key **value**
4. `echo "$var=${var_fixed}" >>.env` - write key=value pair to `.env` file

Answer (score 7):

For me this was caused by having `export` in the `.env` file:

```
export ENDPOINT=https://endpoint.io
```

Instead do

```
ENDPOINT=https://endpoint.io
```

See also: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/701#issuecomment-506884219

Answer (score 0):

Use without any space

```
 env_varible="envvariable"
```